# Call EXCEL method from Module

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Creating module:

```
module CF
  def work_sheet(excel_doc_name, workbook_name)
    dir_to_excel = Dir.pwd + '/lib/config/data/'
    read_workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse("#{dir_to_excel}#{excel_doc_name}")
    worksheet = read_workbook["#{workbook_name}"]
  end
end
```

Call this method from module:

```
Given(/^Excel read$/) do
  include CF
  work_sheet("Login.xlsx", "Login_info")
end
```

Error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `work_sheet' for #<Object:0x442f158>
```

Please check [image: Screen]

Comment: Note that you can format the code in your question by placing 4 spaces at the start of each line (or select the text and click the code sample button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the methods of a module in a step definition, you need to add the module to the [World](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World).

In your `env.rb` (or a file required by it) add the following line (after you have required the module file):

```
World(CF)
```

You should also remove the `include CF` line from the step definition.